# How to use an If statement comparing two columns in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe table that consists of two columns, and I am trying to compare the two columns using IF statements.

[My dataframe table looks like this]
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jN9w.png

I am trying to say for each row:
If positive>negative then "Positive Review"
Else "Negative Review"

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Read about `ifelse`.

Comment: `ifelse(data$postive > data$negative, "Positive Review", "Negative Review")`